# show that $\mathcal{A}_{f}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

**Given:**
S is set and $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$

**Problem:**
 Showing that $\mathcal{A}_f = \{ f^{-1}(B): B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \}$ is a $\sigma $ - algebra.

**My approach:**
Try to show all three properties of a $\sigma $ - algebra:
So I would like to show that the following three statements hold:

1. $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}_f $ and $S \in \mathcal{A}_f $
2. $\forall A \in \mathcal{A}_f: A^{c} \in \mathcal{A}_f $
3. $A_1,A_2,.... \in \mathcal{A}_f \ \  \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \in \mathcal{A}_f$

I guess I should do something with measurability of a $f$, but I can't figure out what, since I don't know nothing about the measurability of f.

**Question:**
Can someone tell me how I should tackle this problem? 
How can you for example show property (1) in the first place?

Comment: Why don't you focus on the problem and show that ${\cal A_f}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. What do you mean by measurability of $f$???

Comment: Just use set-theoretic properties of preimages. For $1.)$ for example we have $\emptyset \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and thus $$\emptyset =f^{-1}(\emptyset) \in \mathcal{A}_f$$

Comment: $f^{-1}(A \cup B) =f^{-1}(A)  \cup f^{-1}(B).$ Same logic with the complementary.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven thank you. You are getting me in the right direction. I  understand that $\emptyset = f^{-1}(\emptyset) \in \mathcal{A}_f$. So how would you then show that $S \in \mathcal{A}_f$.   You would like to show that there is some set,say $F$, such that $F \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f^{-1}(F) =S$ right? How would you do that?

Comment: @copper.hat yes I mean the measurability of f

Comment: @UBM Thanks, I didn't think of that, even though it is quiet trivial hahah. Then property 2 and 3 immediately follow, but how to do property 1?

Comment: @Phoenix_10: property 1 is even easier. $\emptyset \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{R} \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ so $\emptyset = f^{-1}(\emptyset) \in \mathcal{A}_f$ and $S = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) \in \mathcal{A}_f.$

Comment: @UBM but how do you know that $S = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$, since that is only true when f is surjective right?

Comment: @Phoenix_10: No, this is always true whether $f$ is surjective or not. Suppose we have a not surjective function $f$ such that $f(S) = B \subset \mathbb{R}.$ Then $f^{-1}(B) = S$, and since  $B \subset \mathbb{R},$ we have that $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) = S$